# Ganache get the mnemonic of all accounts

Tags: ganache

When I install the `Ganache` a `mnemonic` is shown at the user interface.

I think that the `mnemonic` which is shown in `Ganache` UI is for first account (`account[0]`).

As a test I open the MetaMask select **restore from seed** feature enter above `mnemonic` and I get the account that its public and private key are same as `account[0]` which is shown in `Ganache`

So, is it possible that I can have the mnemonic for other accounts.

A syntax is shown in front of `mnemonic` that is `m/44'/60'/0'/0/account_index`, I think there must be a way to change `account_index` here but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mnemonic you have is for every account.

In regards to the HD path `m/44'/60'/0'/0/account_index`, `account[0]` is basically `account[account_index]` so if you simply just use the "Create Account" function on Metamask, you are increasing the `account_index` for that account recovered under that mnemonic.

So `account[0 - whatever]` under your Ganache setup is basically a path with a HDPath base of `m/44'/60'/0'/0` that are just children paths using the same recovery mnemonic.

Comment: I thought that each mnemonic is for one private and public account, which seems to be wrong. As you mentioned *The mnemonic you have is for _every account_.*

Answer (score 2):

I think the ganache has used a single mnemonic for 10 ethereum accounts. because when I was using a random account and logged out, then I used a mnemonic  to replace the new password for the meta mask. Read more on:https://truffleframework.com/docs/ganache/using

In docs:

```
The Accounts & Keys page sets details about the number of accounts created,
and whether to use a specific mnemonic or let Ganache generate its own.
```

Comment: When I enter the `mnemonic ` I get the public and private key of first account not all of them !

Comment: Yes. Try `Create Account` to get another account. The accounts will be sorted in order in the ganache. Login first will be always account with index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an account to the MetaMask instance to which you imported the mnemonic. The new account should be `account[1]`